# Adding a Kernel to Windows Boot Menu

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, kernel

I'm trying to get a kernel started and I'm having problems
getting it on the Windows boot menu. I've written and built
a small test kernel with [this guide](http://ksrenevasan.blogspot.com/2005/10/writing-multiboot-pe-kernels-using.html), but I don't know how to
get the actual PE file to connected to the boot menu.

I read [here](http://dc0d32.blogspot.com/2012/02/writing-kernel-in-windows-with-visual.html) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that you use `BCDedit` to add it to the boot menu,
so I tried to do it this way:

```
bcdedit /create /d "Test Boot" /application bootsector
// gave the guid: {1c8a5e74-84ff-11e3-a4da-8050f0e41ed6}
bcdedit /set {1c8a5e74-84ff-11e3-a4da-8050f0e41ed6} path \Users\Taylor\Workspace\boot\kernel.exe
```

Here's the output of the working directory:

```
C:\Users\Taylor\Workspace\boot>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9249-0892

 Directory of C:\Users\Taylor\Workspace\boot

06/03/2014  04:03 PM    <DIR>          .
06/03/2014  04:03 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/02/2014  09:17 PM               980 kernel.c
06/02/2014  09:20 PM            16,384 kernel.exe
06/02/2014  09:04 PM               372 kernel.h
06/02/2014  09:20 PM               847 kernel.map
06/02/2014  09:17 PM               825 kernel.obj
               5 File(s)         19,408 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  61,853,569,024 bytes free
```

But it still doesn't show up on my boot menu. I probably am missing some basic information, but I can't seem to find very much information on using Microsoft tools to develop kernels. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Unless you can afford the license or are part of an educational institution having a license, there is no way to develop a kernel based *on* Windows. If you'd like a FLOSS alternative, check out ReactOS. Aside from that there are very strict rules on where the kernel image may sit, although it may have changed with Windows 8 or newer.

Comment: I'm just using tools on Windows, I'm not writing a kernel based on Windows.

Comment: @0xC0000022L That doesn't seem relevant. The question is how to get the Windows bootloader to boot a custom kernel.

Comment: What does the output of `bcdedit` (no arguments) show after running the `set` command?

Comment: @AndrewMedico: which part of my comment is not relevant? In fact the one about the strict rules seems *very* relevant to me, given the path we are being shown. But I have to hit the bed. So I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @AndrewMedico It only shows the Boot Manager and Boot Loader entries

Comment: @0xC0000022L The part about not being allowed to make derivatives of the Windows kernel. There is no indication in the question that the OP is trying to do that. The linked code (https://github.com/kaushiks/multibootpe) is a simple "Hello, world" boot sector from scratch.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Thanks that looks promising. I'm checking it out now.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I don't see it going beyond building the kernel executable.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Per *Windows Internals* (6th Ed), kernels are not limited to the `\WINDOWS` folder. The bootloader contains an NTFS driver and must be able to handle cases where the Windows installation is an upgrade from a previous version with a different folder name. A related limitation is that files used *by* the Windows kernel during boot must be located in %SYSTEMROOT% because during early kernel initialization there is no guarantee other folders will be accessible.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: I didn't say that. However, if the path given (and for `\SystemRoot` that's virtually never the case) contains reparse points, symlinks, whatnot, the very limited implementation of NTFS in NTLDR may be out of its wits. No more no less is implied in what I stated above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MSDN page for bcdedit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#adding_a_new_boot_entry_in_windows_vista_and_later) states:

> [N]ew boot loader entries are not added to the boot menu automatically. You can place the boot loader entries in any order.

You must use the `bcdedit /displayorder` command to explicitly add your new entry to the menu. For example:

```
bcdedit /displayorder {current} {1c8a5e74-84ff-11e3-a4da-8050f0e41ed6}
```

Comment: wow that was literally right below the command I read. I guess I wasn't reading hard enough, thanks!